# Is it possible to access other file:// URLs via JavaScript on a page loaded via the file:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, file

I have an HTML file that I'm loading via the `file://` protocol (`file:///P:/ProgramData/Snip/html/index.html`) and would like to access another file via JavaScript in the page.

Unfortunately, I get a CORS error when trying to load the file with a `fetch()` request.

Is it possible to access other files in the same folder in this situation?  I would like to load a text file, parse the contents, then display them on the page.

My current solution is to use a local web server, but that adds a few extra steps I'd like to eliminate for my target end user.

Comment: Run a local server, it is not that hard to spin up with node or python. There are a lot of restrictions running off file system. Some browsers have flags you can set, but than you risk your users using that browser on untrusted things.

Comment: Modern browsers don't allow stuff loaded from `file://` URLs to access other files because of security concerns. For example, some products come with documentation in HTML files, and one would load them via `file://` URLs, and you probably would not want to allow them access to any file on your computer.